# How to identify a web page visitor with javascript without using cookies?

Tags: javascript

For a while i have noticed that some of the adverts on the web, extremely related with what i have interested.

I think it's possible by javascript because even i clean all the cookies in my computer, situation is the same.

Anyone points me the right direction ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of new ways to track people via javascript and other tools, [The Evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) Basically sums all of them up into one horrifying nightmare of a cookie. You could also look into HTML5's new localstorage with javascript.